# Symbol command disabled in math mode

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

1.I have located the problem is caused by `\rm` command；

2.There is warnning log when run in **Overleaf**:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "Times New Roman" does not contain requested Script "Math".

 
‪./name.tex‬
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not available for font 'Times New Roman' with script '' and language 'Default'.

 
‪./name.tex‬
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not available for font 'Times New Roman' with script '' and language 'Default'.
```

3.Example：

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\RequirePackage[bold-style=ISO, mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[range={"1D70B, "2605, "2ACB, "2AFD, "23DC}]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={"221A, "221B, "221C}]
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range={"03C0}]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[range={"2A00-"2AFF}]
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{TU}{lmr}{m}{it}
\begin{document}

$(\alpha \in  \rm\mathbf Q\ and \  \alpha != 0）$\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: The command `\rm` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: you should not use `\rm` in latex

Comment: So is there any substitute for it?@DavidCarlisle@egreg

Comment: The parentheses aren't part of the formula and there are two of them: `($\alpha\in\symbf{Q}$ and $\alpha\neq0$)`

Comment: `\mathrm` (`\rm`  isn't even mentioned in the latex manual)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok,thanks for your answer

Comment: @egreg ok,thanks for your answer and suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The command `\rm`, together with the similar two-letter font commands have been deprecated for about 30 years.

Your input is also semantically wrong: you have a parenthetical condition that consists of two formulas connected by “and”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO, mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[range={"1D70B, "2605, "2ACB, "2AFD, "23DC}]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={"221A, "221B, "221C}]
%\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range={"03C0}] % <--- Why?
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[range={"2A00-"2AFF}]

%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{TU}{lmr}{m}{it} % <--- Why?

\begin{document}

($\alpha \in  \symbf{Q}$ and $\alpha \neq 0$)

\end{document}
```

[image]